# Create Serial Number column for Drugs based on its category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a Sno column for drug list. Kindly go through the below sample for reference.
Typ = D-Diabetic drug O-Other drug

```
ID  Date       Typ Drug
123 02/05/2020 D   aaa
123 02/05/2020 D   bbb
123 02/05/2020 D   nnn
123 02/05/2020 O   ccc
123 02/05/2020 O   fff
123 05/06/2020 D   asd
456 12/06/2020 D   wef
456 12/06/2020 D   fgf
456 12/06/2020 O   rty
```

Expected Output

```
ID  Date       Typ Drug Sno
123 02/05/2020 D   aaa  1
123 02/05/2020 D   bbb  2
123 02/05/2020 D   nnn  3
123 02/05/2020 O   ccc  1
123 02/05/2020 O   fff  2
123 05/06/2020 D   asd  1
456 12/06/2020 D   wef  1
456 12/06/2020 D   fgf  2
456 12/06/2020 O   rty  1
```

Comment: From your "expected output" It's not clear to me what the "rule" is meant to be for the `sno` column. What do you mean by "wrong order"? What was the query you tried? If this is a homework assignment, it's polite to let us know. Ideally, also post your DDL (`create table ...`)

Comment: The Sno column should be generated base on Same date and Type of Drug. ID-123 had 5 drugs which categorized 2 type(D,O) on 02/05/2020. @allmhuran

Comment: OK, I think I see the rule you want, "For each drug type, on each date, the serial number should increment in alphabetical order of drug". If that's right, then I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think I see the rule.

"For each drug type, on each date, the serial number should increment in alphabetical order of drug."

OK.

```
select    ID,
          [Date],
          Typ,
          Drug,
          Sno = row_number() over (partition by Date, Typ order by Drug asc)
from      YourTable
```

If you also need to partiton by ID, include that as well:

```
select    ID,
          [Date],
          Typ,
          Drug,
          Sno = row_number() over (partition by ID, Date, Typ order by Drug asc)
from      YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select * row_number() over (partition by ID, Typ order by Drug) as Sno
from tablename
```